# Go lang reflection how to recognize interface underlying type

Tags: go, reflection

For instance :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    arr := []int{}

    var arrI interface{} = arr

    arrValuePtr := reflect.ValueOf(&arrI)
    arrValue := arrValuePtr.Elem()

    fmt.Println("Type: ", arrValue.Type()) // prints: "Type: interface{}
    fmt.Println("Interface value: ", arrValue.Interface()) // prints: "Interface value: []"


    arrValue.Set(reflect.Append(arrValue, reflect.ValueOf(55))) 
    // error: panic: reflect: call of reflect.Append on interface Value
}
```

So is there a way to recognize that arrValue is a slice value rather than interface{} value?
https://play.golang.org/p/R_sPR2JbQx

Comment: Why do you taking pointer of `interface{}`? `arrValue := reflect.ValueOf(arrI)` gives me `Type: int[]`: https://play.golang.org/p/5L1NqItNh1

Comment: Lets start with this example first: https://play.golang.org/p/Nhabg31Sju. In this example if I don't pass arr as pointer I get "reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value" inside appendToSlice method.
Now I wanted to generalize this solution. I wanted to pass any slice to this method(ignore the fact that only int is appended). Updated example:  https://play.golang.org/p/WGtfjpW0EN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have seen, you cannot directly append to the interface. So, you want to get the value associated with the interface and then use it with `Value.Append`.

```
arr := []int{}

var arrI interface{} = arr

arrValuePtr := reflect.ValueOf(&arrI)
arrValue := arrValuePtr.Elem()

fmt.Println("Type: ", arrValue.Type()) // prints: "Type: interface{}
fmt.Println("Interface value: ", arrValue.Interface()) // prints: "Interface value: []"
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(arrValue.Interface()))
arr2 := reflect.ValueOf(arrValue.Interface())
arr2 = reflect.Append(arr2, reflect.ValueOf(55))
fmt.Println(arr2) // [55]
```

Comment: Original slice is still unaffected. 
fmt.Println(arr) //[]
https://play.golang.org/p/f6mjuXl0V3

Comment: It cannot be modified. `arrI` is a *copy* of the original slice's address. Remember that, when you append to a slice, the original slice is not modified, hence the need for an affectation. The only thing you could do is, say, initialize `arr := []int{1}`, modify that value from `arr2` and see the modification in `arr`.

Comment: Ok. I see now. Thanks.